# windows docker pull EOF

Tags: windows, docker, eof, boot2docker, pull

I installed boot2docker on Windows and I am having problems pulling images. I get an EOF error both when directly pulling and when trying to run directly (in that case Docker guesses it has to pull an image). Any ideas why this might be? I put my Docker version and info below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you can do to mitigate this :

1. If you're seeing this error while pulling large images from private repo, It could mean that the private repo is busy, as someone else might be pulling at the same time.
2. If the size of the image which you're pulling is huge and your machine is under-powered you still could see this issue, even though you could be pulling from a public repo.
3. If none of the above applies to you, then I think you've hit a strange bug in docker 1.7, Your best bet is to upgrade the client version to 1.11 or recent.